# Как нарисовать несколько разноцветных эллипсов?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть 5 кнопок, при нажатии на которые я рисую эллипсы.

```
draw.circle(x, y, 10, 10, cavRoot);
```

Функция для отрисовки эллипса:

```
public static void circle(double x, double y, int width, int height, Canvas cv)
    {

        Ellipse circle = new Ellipse()
        {
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            Stroke = Brushes.Red,
            StrokeThickness = 6
        };

        cv.Children.Add(circle);

        circle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double)x);
        circle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (double)y);
    }
```

Я хочу чтобы эллипсы были разных цветов (кнопка1 - красный, кнопка2 - синий, кнопка3 - зеленый) и тд, но не хочу создавать 5 раз функцию для каждой кнопки, только чтобы поменять цвет.
Можно ли функцию как-то изменить, и если да то как?

Comment: Передать цвет как параметр?

Comment: Да как параметр

Comment: так в чем вопрос тогда? Добавьте параметр в функцию и вперед